# Name for interface IWhatsMyName: ISink, ISource

Tags: c#, interface, naming-conventions

Is there any "typical" name for an interface which combines functionality of `ISink` (consumer of any stuff) and `ISource` (producer of any stuff) interfaces? (Similar situation: `IReceive` combined with `ITransmit` would probably get `ITransceive`)...

Answer (score 1):

First to ask is why have a new interface that combines in your case a consumer and a producer interface. Why not just implement each interface separately on your class which allows separation of contracts...a much more flexible and better implementation.

But if you wrap/derive interfaces with a new interface, surely the new interface provides additional functionality and should not be named as a combination of the other interfaces. You should provide a name that makes sense according to what this interface provides. For example hypothetical:

```
interface IAnimal {}

interface IHuman {}

interface ISpecie : IAnimal, IHuman {}
```

...and not IAnimalHuman.

Well this is my 2 cents :)

Comment: Some classes implement `ISink` only, some `ISource` only, some both of them (In one case it is just forwarding in other it is aggregation/transformation etc). For those I just wanted to have nice shorcut expressing the *general* combination (not the specific one).   Regarding the second part: yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for `NativeEnglishCombination(Source, Sink) ?? "Does not exist"`.

Comment: What is the class called that implements both interfaces?

Comment: That's the point. It depends on its specialization. One might be `Distributor` or `Forwarder`, another might be `Transformer` or `Aggregator`, but all implements `ISink` and `ISource`. In general they accept objects on the sink side apply their functionality and emit objects on source side.

Comment: Well, i would have cast the class to the desired interface then where it requires. ISink on accepting objects and ISource when emitting. I think you are chasing your own tail.